# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el formulario al usuario logueado?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

**mi view**

```
@login_required
def agregar(request):
    current_user = request.user 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgregarForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            candidate=form.save(commit=False)
            candidate.user = Producto.objects.get(user=request.user)
            candidate.save()
            print candidate
            return redirect('/cuenta/')
    else:
        form = AgregarForm()

    args = {}
    args['form'] = form
    print args
    return render(request,'users/agregar.html', args)
```

**mi modelo es:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Producto(models.Model):
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True, blank = True, 
    verbose_name='Ingrese el modelo del Producto')
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank = True, 
    verbose_name='color Producto')

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.modelo


def upload_to(self,filename):
    ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username,filename)
    return ruta

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo_user = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
    photo_team = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: El titulo no explica lo que deseas, por favor mejoralo para que sea entendible, ademas podrias dar un contexto a tu pregunta, y explicarno que has intentado y en que has fallado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es guardar el usuario que está logueado actualmente en el sistema (es decir, el `request.user`), basta con hacerlo directamente.

En otras palabras, cambia esta parte de tu código que, dicho sea de paso, no le encuentro sentido (¿estás tratando de guardar un objeto de `Producto` a un campo que tiene una relación con el usuario?):

```
candidate = form.save(commit=False)
candidate.user = Producto.objects.get(user=request.user)
candidate.save()
```

A esto:

```
candidate = form.save(commit=False)
candidate.user = request.user
candidate.save()
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución pero lo que estoy haciendo es probar la funcionalidades